# How would you redirect a (www.) query to the non-www url while still forcing the https://

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Here is my .htaccess file from a managed Wordpress site on Go Daddy. The middle section was added by a popular Wordpress plugin (Really Simple SSL) to force any http:// request to the https:// protocol, but if I input www.my_domain.com into the address bar of any major browser, the unsecure (non SSL) page version will render. Is there a bit of additional code that would force the www. to the secure https:// page?

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^vxj\.f09\.myftpupload\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[5.2.3]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention sample urls FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect in browser? That will give better picture of question thank you.

Comment: What if you change `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^vxj\.f09\.myftpupload\.com$` to ``RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?vxj\.f09\.myftpupload\.com$ ?

Comment: Thank you @Ravinder for taking the time to respond. *After flushing my Wordpress cache, the www. now resolves to the https://..  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @arkascha for responding as well. (This issue has been resolved.)

Answer (score 0):

This posted question is no longer an issue -- after flushing my Wordpress cache, the .htaccess file is redirecting all requests (www.) to the https:// rendering.